# Symfony - second button inline with input field

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I have a form with several input fields and a submit button. now I want to add an extra `FileType` field with an upload button right in front of it. so the user can upload files before submitting the whole form.

I tried to add the button in twig after the input:

```
<button type='submit'>upload</button>
```

However the button is pushed to the next line, as symfony/twig(form_row) adds the Filetype field with 3 divs like this:

```
<div>
    //input field here
</div>

<div>
    //form errors here
</div>

<div class='clear'>    
</div>
```

The button is added after these 3 divs and on the next line. How can I render this inline with the file upload field?

Comment: What about using `form_widget` for that button only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symfony gives you a wide variety of ways to customize how a form is rendered. You can customize this form field by using other form/twig funtions like `form_label()`, `form_widget()` and `form_errors`.

```
<label>{{ form_label(form.file) }}</label>
<div class="inline">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    {{ form_widget(form.file) }} // will render <input type="file" .../> widget
</div>
<div class="errors">
    {{ form_errors(form.file) }}
</div>
```

If you need to do it for all `FileType` likely you need [to create a type extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html) and modify the default widget theme of this `FileType`.

Useful links:

- http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html